# create a vector with size x and value f(x) in octave

Tags: octave

I have to generate a dataset of N data points, which are defined as `t_n=f(x_n)+e`, where e is drawn from normal distribution and `f(x)` is a nonlinear function.
For example, i have a function `f(x)=x²+2x+10`, how can i fill a vector `v`, such:

```
x = 1:1:100;
v = create(f(x)+normrnd(0,1),x);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many methods to do this. Here I show you how to do it with anonymous functions http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Anonymous-Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions

```
f = @(x) polyval ([1 2 10], x)
x = 1:100;
v = f(x) + normrnd (0, 1, size (x));
```

Or without a function:

```
x = 1:100;
v = x.^2 + 2.*x + 10 + normrnd (0, 1, size (x));
```

I've adjusted x here so that the noise is visible:

```
x = linspace (-3, 3);
v = f(x) + normrnd (0, 1, size (x));
plot (x, v)
grid on
```

[image]